# Get a line from txt file to php

Tags: php, file, email

I wan't to send an email from a php using this :

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

And I have a .txt file with this:

```
...
send_email_to : example@example.com
...
```

So, what I want to do is to get the line `send_email_to` and put it on `$to` on the php. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Sure. You can read the text file, parse the relevant line(s), and change your `$to` var.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the whole file content format is as you provided at your example, you can do something like this:

```
$options = array();

$fileResource = fopen('file.txt', 'r');
while (($line = fgets($fileResource)) !== false) {
    list($key, $value) = explode(' : ', $line);
    $options[$key] = trim($value);
}
fclose($fileResource);

echo $options['send_email_to'] ?? null; //example@example.com
```

Comment: Not too sure `list()` will know what you mean since `explode()` returns an array.

Comment: `list` will simply reassign values from `explode(...)[0]` and `[1]` to the new variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
foreach(file("file1.txt") as $line) {
$pieces = explode(":", $line);
$to = trim($pieces[1]);
//Send email here if you want to send email to each one in the file.
}
```

Comment: Except you get a warning and invalid email each time no colon exists in the line.